# javafx changing default style of menu item

Tags: java, css, javafx-2

I want to change the default style of JavaFX menu item, so adding css but not getting worked. So how can I change the default style of menu item? Also how can I check that whether my css is connected or not?

```
.menu-item:focused {
 -fx-background: -fx-accent; 
 -fx-background-color: #AA0000; 
 -fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

used this but not working.

Comment: How the css file is being loaded to the scene?

Comment: thanks @ulukbiy style sheet is not loaded properly thats why not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

setting the style Sheet for the Current scene thats why not Working
Set style sheet to root  then define your css class and used it to menu item to solve problem

```
this.getScene().getRoot().getStylesheets().add("com/proj/folder/styles/menuitemcss.css");
```